# Repositioning of controls in windows forms in different OS

Tags: .net, windows

I am working on Windows Application in .NET(C#) which is required to work on different operating system. It is working properly on windows 8 but when tried to run on Windows 7 some of its controls are being interchanged.
Please let me know if operating system has impact on changing controls position.

Comment: Probably the monitor resolution have an impact.

Comment: Yes, `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Change the size of all items` can do that. google for DPI